# iOS: Can users read the data stored in Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, core-data

I'm writing an iOS app and want to use Core Data to persist some data locally for performance and UX. I would like to know if what stored in Core Data can be read and accessed by the users. If so, is it possible to make it unreadable for users. Is there a risk to store other users' Firebase user ids in Core Data.

Thanks for considering my question.

Comment: Sounds rather sketchy to me. Let's say you've actually tested out everything. Then why ask this question? Focus on your *real* concern - Firebase IDs. Please, add some code that is duplicatable. Not trying to be offending to a new contributor, but exactly **what** are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in core data is encrypted with device passcode. so technically it can be read by user.

This question related you your question.
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147312/is-data-stored-in-core-data-on-ios-secure

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question.